# Websocket 1006 error

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

We are using NodeJS (express framework), Backbone and Websocket for backend.

If the data is less than 1 MB then we dont see any issues.

But if the data is more than 1 MB then we get 1006 error ( Client closed event ).

When we took a closer look, we saw that when data is pushed to Database via post, we get a client closed connection (if the data is more than 1 MB).

I read somewhere that data is capped at 1 MB for this case.

Is there any place where that 1 MB can be increased?

Comment: Are you sending this 1 MB data over  websockets or normal HTTP?

Comment: Sending this data over websockets.

Comment: Are you sending a file or binary data? Have you looked into binary streaming with socket.io?

Comment: It is not the file...it is the "actual data". Can you guide me on the binary streaming?

Comment: http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary With that you can `stream` data regardless of size.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications.           This is the websocket we use currently.. so your suggestion is to change this to socket.io?

Comment: Since you tagged socket.io, I assumed you are using it. However, if you are using Node.js and websockets, I would suggest you to use socket.io. Then, you would also use the socket.io library for both frontend and backend that'd provide you with new possibilities, like the one I mentioned.

Comment: Could you please add some of your backend and frontend code code as to how you are sending and how you are receiving data?

Comment: this.socket.send(obj); This is how the data is sent today.  But there is a talk for using socket.io. but we arent sure why the data is capped at 1 MB,